# AngularJS does not update after value change

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

My intention is to update the navigation bar after the user login. Basically, it should change `Login` to `Hi, {{usr.username}}` right after the login.
However, it does not update after logging in and I have to click on `Login` again to trigger the change. However, in the console, the user info is logged right after the login.

In the index.html, the part of the code looks like:

```
<div class="item" ng-click="loginmodal()" ng-hide="loggedIn">Log in</div>
<div class="item" ng-show="loggedIn">Hi, {{usr.username}}</div>
```

where `$scope.loggedIn` is initialized as false and `$scope.usr` as null. I am using firebase for authentication:

```
FirebaseRef.authWithPassword({
    "email"    : email,
    "password" : password
}, function(error, authData) {
    if (error) {
        console.log('Login Failed!', error);
    } else {
        console.log('Authenticated successfully with payload:', authData);
        FirebaseRef.child("users").child(authData.uid).once('value', function(dataSnapshot) {
            $scope.usr = dataSnapshot.val();
        });

        $scope.loggedIn = true;

        console.log($scope.usr);
        console.log($scope.loggedIn);
    }
});
```

In console, I have `$scope.loggedIn` as true, but have `$scope.usr`as null.

Is it wrong how I am using the `authWithPassword()` function or can I force the change to be updated?

Comment: I thinks the $scope.user is in another scope, try use a service to update this value.

Comment: As @Miszy says, you should use AngularFire's `$firebaseAuth` service, which handles updates to the scope for you. See https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html#section-angular-authentication

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AngularJS won't update the view if any changes to the `$scope` object are done outside of its `$digest` loop.

But worry not, Firebase is such a popular tool it has a AngularJS service. It's called *AngularFire* and you should be using it instead of global Firebase object.

So your code will be something similar to:

```
var auth = $firebaseAuth(FirebaseRef);
auth.$authWithPassword({
    email: email,
    password: password
}).then(function (authData) {
    console.log('Authenticated successfully with payload:', authData);
    var sync = $firebase(FirebaseRef.child("users").child(authData.uid));
    var syncObject = sync.$asObject();
    syncObject.$bindTo($scope, "usr");
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.error('Login Failed!', error);
});
```

Read more [in the documentation of AngularFire](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html)

Answer (score 3):

Try calling `$scope.$digest()` right after changing `$scope.usr` value.
Anyway, notice that you call to Firebase to get the user is asynchronous, so I wouldn't put dependent code after this call, but inside the callback.

Comment: I tried $digest and $apply. Neither worked....It works fine now. I am using AngularFire.

Answer (score 0):

Call $scope.$apply();

```
FirebaseRef.child("users").child(authData.uid).once('value', function(dataSnapshot) {

   $scope.$apply(function(){
      $scope.usr = dataSnapshot.val();
   });

});
```